# Update the ID3 tags of S3 bucket files

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, id3-tag

In my AWS s3 bucket I have thousand of mp3 files and I want to modify the ID3 tags for those files. please suggest the best way.

Comment: I'd do it programatically. one by one. Also, you could take a look at http://s3browser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to give you the bad news, but only way to do is downloading files one by one update id3 tags and upload them back to s3 bucket. You cannot edit files in place, because AWS S3 is object storage, meaning it keeps data in key: value pairs, key is the folder/filename, value is the file content. It's not suitable for file system, databases, etc.

If you do it this way, one warning, check if you have versioning is on or off for your bucket. Sometimes it's nice to have versioning handled automatically by S3 but, you should remember that each version adds to the storage space that you're paying for.

If you want to edit/modify your files every now and then, you can use AWS EBS or EFS. Both EBS and EFS are block storages, and you can attach them to any EC2 instance, then you can edit/modify your files. The difference between EBS and EFS mainly is, EFS can be attached to multiple EC2 instances at the same time, and share the files in between them.

One more thing about EBS and EFS though, to reach your files, you need to attach it to an EC2 instance. There is no other way to reach your files as easily as in S3.